# Node js Multiple Query Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How do we handle multiple query promises in node js and mongo using async function ?

For example I wanted to add new query which is and then handle the gallery result the way const file result being handled.

```
const gallery = await gfs.findManyAsync({ metadata: vehicle.VIN })
```

## Here is my current code

```
 async function myFunction() {

        gfs.findOneAsync = promisify(gfs.findOne);
        gfs.findManyAsync = promisify(gfs.files.find);


        const totalCount = await Vehicle.model.count({})
        const vehicles = await Vehicle.model
            .find(query, {}, pagination)
            .sort(sortOrd + sortType)

        const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / size)
        const promises = vehicles.map(async vehicle => {
            let ImageList = vehicle.ImageList.split(',')
            let profile_name = ImageList[0].split('/').pop();


            const file = await gfs.findOneAsync({
                $and: [{
                    $or: [{
                        metadata: vehicle.VIN
                    }]
                },
                {
                    $or: [{
                        filename: profile_name
                    }]
                }
                ]
            })

            const gallery = await gfs.findManyAsync({ metadata: vehicle.VIN })

            // const gallery = await gfs.findManyAsync({ metadata: vehicle.VIN })

            // console.log("Gallery :" , gallery)

            if (file) {

                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
                    const url = `http://localhost:3002/api/vehicle/file/${file.filename}`
                    vehicle.FileData = url
                    resolve()

                })
            }
        })

        try { } catch { (err) }

        await Promise.all(promises)

        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "success",
            pageNo: pageNo,
            totalRecords: vehicles.length,
            data: vehicles,
            totalPages: totalPages

        })
    }
```